# Windows 8.1 Upgrade from 8 failed at "User Account installation...."

Tags: windows-8, upgrade, windows-installation, windows-8.1

I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 8 Pro to Windows 8.1 Pro RTM.
My computer is Asus 1215B.
The installation process stopped responding at screen "Next, User Profile is installing..." or something like this, don't remember the exact syntax...

Thanks for you help...

Comment: wait until the Update is offered in the Store. If you still have issues, post more details.

Comment: But it has released at MSDN so why should i wait?

Comment: it was released that Developers can update their apps to 8.1, but it was not released that normal users can use it. MS will also release a larger stability update to fix several bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I turned off the wifi and the installation continued ...